# SQL Server UPPERCASE for all data for all columns in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know how to convert all data to UPPERCASE for all columns name and the values in them for a table. The data may contain `int` but it will ignore it. Something I did was to manually update column 1 by 1 which is time consuming.

Is there any statement like:

```
UPDATE cust SET cust.* = UPPER(cust.*)
```

Thank you~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is probably your only option.  Something like this should would using `FOR XML` querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
declare @query varchar(max)
set @query = ''

select @query =
  STUFF((
    select ';UPDATE ' + table_name + ' SET ' + column_name + ' = UPPER(' + column_name + ')'
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    order by table_name, column_name
    for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '')

execute(@query);
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/655e1/1)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't to that directly. You need to specify each column names that need to be updated. eg

```
UPDATE tablename
SET    col = UPPER(col)
       colN = UPPER(colN)
```

But, it's not the end of the world. You can still do that but with *Dynamic SQL*.